# "Gallery" app Share view in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, view, gallery, share

The "Gallery" Application in iOS ( atleast the newest version ) has a nice share view, which is black, and each share media ( facebook, twitter, mail, etc ) Is in a different square. I will upload an image if nobody knows it.

I wanted to use this view and I wanted to know - is that a standard view in the ios library or will I have to create a custom view like it by myself?

Tnx for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It's a `UIActivityViewController`, available since iOS 6.0.

Comment: Thank you :) So basically I use this if the ios version is >6, otherwise my old menu?

Comment: @Niv Yes, except it would be >= 6.0.